# htaccess redirect multiple domains to central domain

Tags: .htaccess

Hi if have 3 domain names with a dns that point at one central site with trough a central htaccess file.
I would like to redirect the site by dns to the central site + subdirectory containing the domain name.

for example:

- testsite1.com => thesite.com/testsite1/
- testsite2.com => thesite.com/testsite2/
- testsite3.com => thesite.com/testsite3/

my idea

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.bla1.com$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bla1.com$

RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.com(/[*]) http://bla2.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, `RewriteRule` is not applied to a `HTTP_HOST`, only on a `REQUEST_URI`.

So You can do this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example.com$
 RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Note however, that ".com" will not be stripped from the hostname that is passed in the new path

Btw, "301" is "Moved Permanently". I am not sure You want that, but anyway, it is a common good practice to first use 302 status when redirecting until you're done testing and everything is finalized

Comment: Nu the domain looks like www.bla.com/wwww.bla1.com How can i only get www.bla2.com/bla1?